# Get the N smallest [Comparable] items in a set

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have an unsorted Collection of objects [that are comparable], is it possible to get a sub list of the collection of the list without having to call sort?

I was looking at the possibility of doing a SortedList with a limited capacity, but that didn't look like the right option.

I could easily write this, but I was wondering if there was another way.

I am not able to modify the existing collection's structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't want to call `sort()`, it seems like you are trying to avoid an *O(n log(n))* runtime cost.  There *is* actually a way to do that in *O(n)* time -- you can use a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

There are methods to do this in the Guava libraries (Google's core Java libraries); look in `Ordering` and check out:

- [`public <E extends T> List<E> Ordering.leastOf(Iterable iterable, int k)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#leastOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29)
- [`public <E extends T> List<E> Ordering.greatestOf(Iterable iterable, int k)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#greatestOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29)

These are implementations of [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_select#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm), and since they're written generically, you could just call them on your `Set` and get a list of the `k` smallest things.  If you don't want to use the entire Guava libraries, the docs link to the source code, and I think it should be straightforward to port the methods to your project.

If you don't want to deviate too far from the standard libraries, you can always use a sorted set like `TreeSet`, though this gets you logarithmic insert/remove time instead of the nice *O(1)* performance of the hash-based `Set`, and it ends up being *O(n log(n))* in the end.  Others have mentioned using heaps.  This will also get you *O(n log(n))* running time, unless you use some of the [fancier heap variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants).  There's a [fibonacci heap implementation in GraphMaker](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/analysis-of-java-implementations-of-fibonacci-heap/) if you're looking for one of those.

Which of these makes sense really depends on your project, but I think that covers most of the options.

Comment: I've never heard of that library before. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a sorted set. Insert the first N items from your unsorted collection into your sorted set. Then for the remainder of your unsorted collection:

1. insert each item in the sorted set
2. delete the largest item from the sorted set
3. Repeat until you've processed all items in the unsorted collection

Comment: Thats not a bad solution, since it still is considered to be n operations on my part. [Yes, there is sorting on the SortedSet's part]

Comment: This only works if the initial collection is a Set.  If it is a list, then the sorted set will discard duplicates ...

Comment: Well you could use a SortedBag to solve that: http://bit.ly/e2mave.  But there are also less expensive options than sorting the whole data set.

Comment: If you want to go this way, a PriorityQueue would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Kevin: It might be, but of course that's not really guaranteed, and even at best "much" more efficient is unlikely [e.g., insertion into either a priority queue or a tree-based set will be O(log N)].

Comment: @Stephen C: It is true that I treated it as "N smallest unique values". Obviously,  if you want to allow duplicates, you use a multiset instead of a set.

Comment: It appears that if you want the results in sorted order, then yeah, sometimes a SortedSet can beat a PQ.  My mistake.  However, Ordering.leastOf() (the current top-rated answer) is 3-5x faster than either of these anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: It's nice to have actual numbers from the lead Guava developer.

Comment: @Kevin: yes -- and if it was built into the standard library, I'd have no problem with recommending it (e.g., in C++, which does include it, I've done so). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380568/algorithm-to-find-k-smallest-numbers-in-array-of-n-items/5380672#5380672. Its omission from Java's standard library strikes me as unfortunate, but such is life.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put all of them into a [max heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) with a fixed size of N, conditionally, if the item is smaller than the largest in the max heap (by checking with the `get()` "peek" method).  Once you have done so they will, by definition, be the N smallest.  Optimal implementations will perform with `O(M)+lg(N)` or `O(M)` (where M is the size of the set) performance, which is theoretically fastest.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
MaxHeap maxHeap = new MaxHeap(N);
for (Item x : mySetOfItems) {
  if (x < maxHeap.get()) {
    maxHeap.add(x);
  }
}
```

The [Apache Commons Collections class PriorityBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/PriorityBuffer.html) seems to be their flagship binary heap data structure, try using that one.

Comment: the apache common's just has a function for everything doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

don't you just want to make a heap?