# top-k queries solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

Does anybody has solution for top-k queries problem.
Problem is I have stream of infinite number and I need to come up with solution which will give me top k items in the stream.

This is interview question. I am looking for C++ solution.

This is how would i solve the problem. But here I will need to read the entire `stream/file`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> freq_table_t;
typedef std::multimap<std::size_t, freq_table_t::const_iterator> top_n_t;
size_t n = 5;

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    if ( ifs.peek() == EOF )
        return 1;

    std::string line;
    freq_table_t freq_table;

    while( ifs.good()&& std::getline(ifs,line) ) {
        if ( freq_table.insert(std::make_pair(line, 1 )).second == false )
            freq_table[line]++;
    }
    ifs.close();

    top_n_t top5;
    for (freq_table_t::const_iterator it = freq_table.begin(); it != freq_table.end(); ++it) {
        if (top5.size() < n || it->second > top5.begin()->first)
            top5.insert(std::make_pair(it->second, it));
        if (top5.size() == n + 1)
            top5.erase(top5.begin());
    }
    for ( top_n_t::reverse_iterator ritr = top5.rbegin(); ritr != top5.rend(); ++ritr)
        std::cout << ritr->second->first << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interview is over now, I could not answer and did not find answer on google also, so I am looking for somebody who can explain me the solution

Comment: I don't think this is a completely unfair question, he obviously isn't being interviewed right now.  I would treat this like a homework question, and lead the OP to an answer rather than just give him one.  Plus I'm kind of curious about this myself.

Comment: Asking interview Q's here is not forbidden just please add your inputs to the Question about what you feel about the solution or atleast your thoughts about it even if it is the faintest idea. Voting to Re-Open.

Comment: Voting to reopen now that the OP has edited in their attempt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find k smallest numbers in array of n items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380568/algorithm-to-find-k-smallest-numbers-in-array-of-n-items)

Answer (score 3):

- Create a `std::set<int> top`
- For each number that you get from the stream:
- -- Add the number to the set
- -- If `top.size() > k`, remove the smallest element of the set.

At each point, `top` contains up to `k` largest items in the set (the number will be less than `k` if there were fewer than `k` distinct items in the stream up to this point).
Coding this in C++ should be trivial.

Comment: You're giving the largest-k, avinash is looking for k-most-frequent, based on the freq_table, etc. in the poster's code.

Comment: @James The code has been added after I answered the question. The OP contained the first three lines.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing dasblinkenlight's answer:

Maintain a min priority-queue. For each element in the stream, compare the element with the smallest element on the queue. If it's larger, then dequeue the smallest element and enqueue the new element. As a base case, the initialize the queue to the first `k` elements of the stream.

At the end of the stream, your priority queue will contain the largest `k` elements.

Given `n` elements in the stream, this algorithm will run in `n log k` time.

Comment: I think OP is asking for k - most frequent elements and not the largest of the stream