# performance of Stream.sorted().limit()

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, time-complexity, java-stream

Java Streams sport both `sorted` and `limit` methods, which respectively return a sorted version of a stream and return a stream just returning a specified number of items of a stream. When these operations are applied in succession, such as in:

```
stream.sorted().limit(qty).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

is the sorting is performed in a way that sorts `qty` items or is the entire list sorted? In other words, if `qty` is fixed, is this operation in `O(n)`? The documentation doesn't specify the performance of these methods alone or in conjunction with each other.

The reason I ask is that the obvious imperative implementation of these operations would be to sort and then limit, taking time `Θ(n * log(n))`. But these operations together can be performed in `O(n * log(qty))` and a smart streaming framework could view the entire stream before executing it to optimize this special case.

Comment: The entire stream is sorted.

Comment: It depends on this stream's characteristics; if its underlying `Spliterator` reports that the stream is `SORTED`, then `sort()` is a no-op; otherwise, as already mentioned, the whole stream is sorted, which means that all the elements produced by the stream must be siphoned prior to beginning the sorting operation -- and that's only logical

Comment: @fge ... but ... thinking about it ... there are algorithms that will get the k smallest elements of a `N` element unsorted list in `O(N)`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380568/algorithm-to-find-k-smallest-numbers-in-array-of-n-items.  It should be possible to implement the algorithm for Java 8 streams, though not the way the OP is trying to do it.

Comment: @StephenC I don't believe that such algorithms are applicable for streams, to be honest; how would you then deal with `.sorted().filter(x -> true).filter(x -> true).limit()`? The underlying `Stream` implementation has no way of knowing that in fact the predicate is a no op.

Comment: @fge A lazy pipeline would perform that in `O(n * log(c))` where `c` is the number of items that must be read from the sorted list to satisfy the predicates and the limit.

Comment: @fge - Yea.  My thought is that you would need to combine `sorted` and `limit` into a single component.  Your example would then be: `stream.filter(x -> true).filter(x -> true).smallestK(qty)`.  (Or you could put the filter steps after `smallestK`.)

Comment: Such optimizations -- such as fusing sorting and truncation -- are theoretically possible, and we did consider such things when designing streams.  However, the tradeoffs required were not good; it would have added broad complexity for narrow benefit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me start by making the general point that the Java language specification places few restrictions on how streams are implemented. So it's really not too meaningful to ask about the performance of Java streams: it will vary significantly between implementations.

Also note that `Stream` is an interface. You can create your own class that implements `Stream` to have any performance or special behaviour on `sorted` that you want. So really asking about the performance of `Stream` makes no sense even within the context of one implementation. The OpenJDK implementation has lots of classes that implement the `Stream` interface.

Having said that, if we look at the OpenJDK implementation, sorting of streams ends up in `SortedOps` class (see source [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/SortedOps.java)) you will find that the sorting methods end up returning extensions of stateful operations. For example:

```
private static final class OfInt extends IntPipeline.StatefulOp<Integer>
```

These methods check if the upstream is already sorted in which case they just pass it to the downstream. They also have special exceptions for sized streams (i.e. upstream) which preallocate the arrays that they end up sorting which will improve efficiency (over a `SpinedBuffer` that they use for unknown size streams). But whenever the upstream is not already sorted they accept all items, then sort them and then send to the `accept` method of the downstream instance.

So the conclusion from this is that the OpenJDK `sorted` implementation collects all items, then sorts, then sends downstream. In some cases this will be wasting resources when the downstream will then discard some elements. You are free to implement your own specialised sort operation that is more efficient than this for special cases. Probably the most straightforward way is to implement a `Collector` that keeps a list of the n largest or smallest items in the stream. Your operation might then look something like:

```
.collect(new CollectNthLargest(4)).stream()
```

To replace

```
.sorted().limit(4)
```

Comment: OP I can add an efficient implementation of the collector I suggest in the last para if you are interested.

Comment: You can for didactic purposes but it isn't a priority for me.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Ok thanks - I'll leave it out as I don't think it'll really add anything to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's a special collector in my [StreamEx](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#least-int-) library which performs this operation: [`MoreCollectors.least(qty)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#least-int-):

```
List<?> result = stream.collect(MoreCollectors.least(qty));
```

It [uses](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/4c04f51184b9dceb8e3e2123c1755bef7b853843/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.java#L497) PriorityQueue inside and actually works significantly faster with small qty on unsorted inputs. Note however if input is mostly sorted, then `sorted().limit(qty)` may work faster as TimSort is incredibly fast for presorted data.

Answer (score 3):

That's implementation-dependent and might also depend on whether the stream pipeline can "see through" potential operations between the `sorted()` and the `limit()`.

Even if you were to ask about the OpenJDK implementation it is subject to change since the javadocs make no guarantees about the runtime behavior. But no, currently it does not implement a k-min selection algorithm.

You also have to keep in mind that `sorted()` doesn't work on infinite streams unless they already have the `SORTED` characteristic.

Comment: Unless they already have the `SORTED` characteristic and null comparator.