# How to get Kth largest element of a DoubleStream in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What's the best way of getting the Kth largest element in a DoubleStream in java?

I know we can do .max().getDouble() to get the largest element.

Comment: Did you try to search for it? There are plenty of questions dealing with finding the k-th largest element in various data structures.

Comment: [No code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode) and [no attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt), please see [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Comment: How can this be too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doubleStream.boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .skip(k - 1)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

Will give you the k<sup>th</sup> largest element, or `null` if there are less than k elements in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
OptionalDouble kthLargest = stream
        .map(i -> -i) // Trick to sort in reverse order
        .sorted()
        .distinct() // Remove duplicates
        .map(i -> -i)
        .skip(k - 1)
        .findFirst();
```

Comment: @Holger Stream may contain less than `k` elements

Comment: @Holger would this solution better faster/more memory efficient than using a boxed stream to sorted descending (which might be easier to read)?

Comment: @Malte Hartwig: that depends on the stream size and on the implementation. AFAIK, when using `distinct()` with the current implementation, you have the boxing overhead anyway. But if you really need this operation to be efficient, you should use neither, but rather do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380568/2711488); it’s the same for the k smallest or largest elements.

Comment: What requirement is satisfied by calling `distinct()`?

Comment: @shmosel some commenters asked how duplicate entries should be treated: Should the second largest element of [1,2,3,3] be 3, or 2? Since NeedleBallista hadn't answered in time, the distinct call was added as an option to ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the stream, transform it to an array and get the item at array.length-k.

Example:

```
private static double getKth(DoubleStream ds, int k) {
    double[] array = ds
        .sorted()
        .toArray();
    return array[array.length-k];
}
```

You should add validation to make sure `k` has a legit value

Comment: Or use skip and limit instead of `.toArray();`

Comment: @c0der mind showing some code ?

Comment: I will give it a try (I am not the down voter)

Comment: I did post some code, but got a not-so-nice comment from @Holger, so I deleted it.  Anyway I see others who used skip and limit

Comment: hmmm two downvotes without comments. Very helpful... I tested it with a few different cases on my machine and it seems to work just fine!

Comment: @c0der yes, if you sort in reverse order you can skip (no need to limit though).

Comment: See other answers that use limit. Your answer produces the Kth smallest.

Comment: @c0der  the others use limit/skip since they sorted in reverse order. I'm using normal sorting which means that the last element is the biggest and `array.length-k` is the kth element. Had I returned `array[k]` it was the kth smallest.

Comment: Try running: `double[] array = DoubleStream.of(4,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,9,0)
            .sorted()
            .toArray();
        System.out.println(array[array.length-2]);` and see that it outputs 8 as required.

Comment: You are right. My mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have `DoubleStream`, make it `sorted()` in reverse order (DESC). Then  `limit(k)` and sort ASC and take the `first`.

```
.boxed()
.distinct() //in case you want to ignore repeating values
.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
.limit(k)
.sorted()
.findFirst());
```

Comment: It will return k-th smallest element instead of the largest.

Comment: what if the list has duplicates till the nth number suppose we want to find the 2nd largest and the array is 2,1,6,6
by sorting it will give 6,6,2,1 and the 2nd will give 6 but that isn't true

Comment: @xenteros You limit `k` smallest elements

Comment: @Saramali check the update. It depends on the definition of kth largest value.Some people will skip the repeated values and some won't

Comment: It still finds the Kth **smallest** element. Imagine `k=1`, it would take the smallest element.

Comment: Have you tried your code? I just did for the benefit of the doubt, and it returns the kth smallest element.

Comment: `DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 6, 3, 8, 1)
                    .sorted()
                    .limit(1)
                    .boxed()
                    .sorted((Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(System.out::println);` prints 1.0, should print 8.0.

Comment: I didn't wake up yet, sorry for that guys

Comment: @xenteros wouldn't it be `.limit(k)` instead of `.limit(1)`?

Comment: @MalteHartwig now it works

Comment: `.boxed() [.distinct()] .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) .skip(k) .findFirst()` that’s all.