# Efficient way to implement search operation in JSON file

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance, search

I have a huge JSON file which is an array of objects containing city crime information. The number of crimes per city is listed as a key/value. I'm parsing it to a hash using yajl/json_gem. 
What is the efficient way to find top 10 cities that have most crimes / least crimes?

Comment: Mind sharing your JSON? Might help future readers help you.

Comment: The city crime information is just an example. The dataset i'm working on is different. But the JSON is in this format {"info":[ {"name": "xyz", "crime_rate": 750}, {"name":"ABC", "crime_rate", "900"}......]} Each object is expected to have 10 keys.

Comment: I don't see how your question can be answered on the basis of the limited information you have given. Can you edit to give a small but complete example, together with the desired result? My reading is that you need only give the hash obtained from the JSON file. (In that sense the fact that it originates from a JSON file is not relevant.) Be sure to assign a variable to the hash (e.g., `h = {...}`), so that readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, an efficient way of traversing through a list to find the `k` min or max elements is with a min or max heap. A [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) is a tree-like data structure that always has the smallest or largest element at the top of the tree, and inserting a new element or deleting an element is `O(log n)`.

Let's say you have N elements in your table and want to keep track of the k max elements (the process is identical for min, you just use a different heap). Per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675816/1743874), storing the data in a max-heap of size k (and dropping values that are smaller than the minimum value in the heap) is an efficient solution to this problem.

The space complexity is `O(n)` (for each element in the table, there is one element in the heap), and the time complexity is `O(n log k)` (because you have to insert `n` elements worst case, and each one takes `log k` time).

Now, on to the implementation: Ruby doesn't have a Heap data structure, but the gem [`algorithms`](https://github.com/Kanwei/Algorithms/) has a heap implemented in C.

I don't want to write the code for you, but I think that from this theory, you should be able to implement an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

I do not expect this to be a complete answer, as the question is not clear, but this may provide the beginnings of a solution.

Suppose

```
h = { "info":[
        {"name": "Paris",     "crime_rate": "750"},
        {"name": "Rome",      "crime_rate": "800"},
        {"name": "London",    "crime_rate": "600"},
        {"name": "Berlin",    "crime_rate": "400"},
        {"name": "Amsterdam", "crime_rate": "700"}
      ]
    }
```

and the cities with the top two and bottom two crime rates are desired.

```
def top_so_many(h, meth, nbr)
  h[:info].public_send(meth, nbr) { |g| g[:crime_rate] }.map { |g| g[:name] }
end

top_so_many(h, :max_by, 2)
  #=> ["Rome", "Paris"]
top_so_many(h, :min_by, 2)
  #=> ["Berlin", "London"]
```

Comment: @SimplLime. Thanks. You're right. I did an edit. While I was at it I created a helper method to  DRY the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

Store your JSON in a variable:

`json = {"info":[ {"name": "xyz", "crime_rate": 750}, {"name":"ABC", "crime_rate", "900"}......]}`

Parse the JSON:

`h = JSON.parse(s)`

Use `find` or `select` to find the required numer, sort, and take 10 first objects

`h.find { |el| el.crime_rate > 500 }.first(10)` # or any other condition