# Calculating custom distance between n-dimensional instances

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am writing a function that calculates distances between training and testing instances. The distances is modified Manhattan distance. I have working code by it becomes too slow when the number of features (columns) increases. Any idea how could I speed it up?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime


def make_random_distance():
    """Generates randomly populated pandas dataframe of a training dataset and a test dataset and caclulates and ret"""
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(10000,1024)))
    print(df.shape)

    #Test dataset
    test=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(1,1024)))


    Calculated_Distances=[]
    #For each test instance
    for ind,roll in test.iterrows():
        print("Working on test instance {}".format(ind))
        #print(ind,roll.values)
        Test_inst = np.array(roll.values) #Features of test instance
        #Dist = custom_distance_b(Test_inst, df)
        Dist = custom_distance(Test_inst, df)
        print("Done calculating distances")

        print("Now sorting dictionary")
        sorted_d = sorted(Dist.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

        # Now we examine the 5NN
        for j in range(5):
            index_com = sorted_d[j][0]
            calc_dist = sorted_d[j][1]
            Calculated_Distances.append([ind, index_com, calc_dist])

    #writes out results
    Calc_Dist=pd.DataFrame(Calculated_Distances,columns=['Test_indx','Training_indx','Distance'])
    #Calc_Dist.to_csv("/home/Code/testing_distances.csv",sep=',',index=False)
    print(Calc_Dist)

    return


def custom_distance(i,df):
    """
    :param i: test instance vector
    :param df: training instances pandas data frame
    :return:
    """

    #First we need to caclulate the standard deviation for each descriptor (row)

    # First caclulate standard deviations for each column (feature) 
    count_ind = 0
    stad_dev = {}
    for column in df:
        stad_dev[count_ind] = df.iloc[:, column].std(axis=0)
        count_ind+=1

    Dist={}
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        temp_dist=0
        for j in range(len(row)):
            dist=float(abs(row[j]-i[j])/(5*stad_dev[j]))
            temp_dist+=min(dist,1.0)
        #print(index,i.values,row.values,temp_dist)
        Dist[index]=round(temp_dist,3)


    return Dist


if __name__=="__main__":
    T1=time.time()
    make_random_distance()
    T2=time.time()
    t=T2-T1
    print("Took {} seconds".format(t))
    print("Took {}".format(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=t))))
```

The current code calculates on my machine for a single test instance the 
distances against 10000 training instances with 1024 features/columns
and retrieves the 5 Nearest Neighbors.

Took 128.5559959411621 seconds
Took 0:02:08.555996

Any idea how I could speed it up? As I will need to calculate thousands of these calculations on my test sets.

Comment: So you want roughly `(10**4)**2/2` distances? that ain't gonna be quick.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. The question is if there is a more efficient implementation as every second counts.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the sort time to find the first 5 by using a min heap: [Algorithm to find k smallest numbers in array of n items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380568/algorithm-to-find-k-smallest-numbers-in-array-of-n-items).

Something else to think about might be that your custom distance is essentially based on the stdev of the column, which isn't going to have a lot of deviation because youve got so many samples. Your stdev is almost never going to move from about 14-15. Which means that if you so desired you could keep all the values in a single array, keep track of where the test value is in that array, and then move up and down from that value to find the closest distance, running the custom distance function on those individual distances after, with extremely high probability of success. This would change your runtime from O(n^3) to O(nlogn)