# Algorithm which returns 3 largest values in array sorted JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am attempting to write a solution to a pretty common alg. Input is a non sorted array and the output should be an array of the three highest valuest sorted.

My approach is to default set the first three items of the array to be the three largest. Loop through every element in the array starting from idx 3 and run each value through a series of functions that compares that value to each of the present 3 highest.

**MY CODE**

```
function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {

  let currentHighest = array[0];
  let secondHighest = array[1];
  let thirdHighest = array[2]
  
  for(i = 3; i < array.length; i++){
    compareFirst(array[i], currentHighest, secondHighest, thirdHighest);
  }
  console.log(currentHighest, secondHighest, thirdHighest)
}


function compareFirst(value, currentHighest, secondHighest, thirdHighest){
  if(value >= currentHighest){

    let pastFirst = currentHighest;
    currentHighest = value;

    compareSecond(pastFirst, secondHighest, thirdHighest)
  }else{
    compareSecond(value, secondHighest, thirdHighest)
  }
}

function compareSecond(value, secondHighest, thirdHighest){
  if(value >= secondHighest){
    
    let pastSecond = secondHighest;
    secondHighest = value;
    
    compareThird(pastSecond, thirdHighest);
  }else{
    compareThird(value, thirdHighest)
  }
}

function compareThird(value, thirdHighest){
  if(value >= thirdHighest){
    thirdHighest = value;
  }
}
```

after this is all finished in the `console.log` I see nothing has changed from the variables I have set above. Meaning the functions are not updating the values set in the parent function.

My approach might be way off but I'm confused as to why the values wont update globally.

Comment: Do you have to do it without sorting the array?

Comment: [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+3+largest+in+array) finds lots of similar questions.

Comment: Your values aren't updating because your local variables share the same name as your global variables. You're changing the local `currentHighest` (the parameter), not the global `currentHighest` (the argument).

Comment: @DM but passing them through params and re-setting their values should update them globally should it not?

Comment: Possibly; if they were objects. [Primitives behave as if they were passed-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Comment: This problem is known as [_k-smallest_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380568/algorithm-to-find-k-smallest-numbers-in-array-of-n-items).  (or k-largest, obviously)  Typical solutions either use a heap, or just recursively partition the array and only descend into the ranges that fall within the first k elements.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has data types passed by value - **Primitive types** (number, boolean, string and etc.) and data types passed by reference - **Objects** (Array, Function, Object).

When you pass primitive type as an argument of the function, you are simply passing the value of the variable. Therefore, when you change the argument of the function passed as a primitive type, this change does not affect the variable passed outside of the function.

When you pass reference data type as an argument of the function, you are passing the address of this variable to the function, not the value itself. That's why if you change the argument passed by reference, then it will be changed as well outside of the function.

In your case, since your are passing the numbers as arguments of the compareFirst, compareSecond and compareThird functions, their values won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, the problem was passing [**Primitive Types**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) as function params, results in having their values changed in only the local function scope but not in the global scope. Using a **Reference Data Type**, in this case: `highestValues` [**Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) to store the values allows me to update them globally as needed from within the child functions.

**SOLUTION**

```
function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {
  let highestValues = {}
  
  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    compareFirst(array[i], highestValues);
  }
  return [highestValues['3'], highestValues['2'], highestValues['1']];
}


function compareFirst(value, highestValues){
  if(!highestValues['1']){
    highestValues['1'] = value;
    
  }else if(value >= highestValues['1']){

    let pastFirst = highestValues['1'];
    highestValues['1'] = value;

    compareSecond(pastFirst, highestValues)
  }else{
    compareSecond(value, highestValues)
  }
}

function compareSecond(value, highestValues){
  if(!highestValues['2']){
    highestValues['2'] = value;
    
  }else if(value >= highestValues['2']){

    let pastSecond = highestValues['2'];
    highestValues['2'] = value;
    
    compareThird(pastSecond, highestValues);
  }else{
    compareThird(value, highestValues)
  }
}

function compareThird(value, highestValues){
  if(!highestValues['3']){
    highestValues['3'] = value;
    
  }else if(value >= highestValues['3']){
    highestValues['3'] = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained what's wrong with your code.

If you're looking for a simpler approach, we can fold the numbers into our target array one step at a time, using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), starting with an array of three copies of `-Infinity`.

At each step we test whether the new number is greater than the highest one, greater than the second-highest one, greater than the third-highest one, or none of the above, and return a three-element array with the new number inserted in the right place.  It might look like this:

```js
const topThree = (ns) => ns.reduce ((m, n) => 
  n > m[2] ? [m[1], m[2], n] : n > m[1] ? [m[1], n, m[2]] : n > m[0] ? [n, m[1], m[2]] : m,
  [-Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]
)

console.log(topThree([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write less code you can think about a similar insertion sort:

```js
function findKLargestNumbers(arr, k = 3) {
  // get first three element and sort them
  let ret = arr.slice(0, k)
  ret.sort()

  // iterate other elements
  for (i = k; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    let x = arr[i];
    for (j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
      // if current value greater then swap (imporant: without break)
      if (x > ret[j]) {
        [x, ret[j]] = [ret[j], x]
      }
    }
  }
  return ret
}
```